Is it possible to ripple delete a clip in Premiere Pro without selecting it via mouse?
I've began doing some projects with Adobe Premiere Pro, and something that it's annoying to me it's that as someone who makes a lot of highlights videos for social media and has to work with hundreds of takes, I don't seem to find a way to ripple delete a clip without selecting it and then pressing "Delete".
I know that Q works to ripple trim the beginning of the clip, and W works to ripple trim the end of the clip, but I can't figure out how to ripple delete the whole clip.
I saw this video where the uploader gives the following workaround for how to ripple delete:




Press Down to go to the end of the video.
Press Back to go to the last frame of the previous video.
Press Q to ripple trim the beginning of the last video.

I set up a Keyboard Magician macro in order to do this, however I've noticed that using this I still get the last frame of the clip I intended to ripple delete.
So I'm wondering, is there another way to achieve this? Ripple delete the clip under the playhead without selecting it.
Having to click on the video with the mouse in order to ripple delete it really kills the editing flow for me.

I'd do this to achieve a similar thing:

Locate your play head at the start of the region you want to delete
Press I to mark an In Point
Play to locate the end of the region you want to delete
Press O to mark an Out Point
Press ' to ripple delete

This also places the deleted clip in your clipboard.
The  ; next to ' is also useful for lifting and copying, but without the ripple.
I often end up using it, then hitting CMDZ to undo it, which keeps it in the clipboard, but undoes the lift.
NB:
SHIFT I and SHIFT O will jump you your current In or Out point.

Thank you very much. With these shortcuts I was able to set up a Keyboard Magician macro to improve my workflow!
